# Python - dataframe, for loop that interprets values of one column, plots range of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe, with 3 columns: (timestamp, arduino read value #1, arduino read value #2) saved and imported via CSV. I basically need to plot several graphs based on this data, but am unsure how to structure what I seek.

Based on the individual values in column 3 (arduino read value #2), I need to plot columns 1 & 2 & 3 in accordance with this reading, but to plot only the prior, and proceeding 5 rows relative to the value in column 3 reading meeting criteria.

There may be several instances of the values in column 3 meeting the criteria, so I assume a for - loop that searches for this value, then plots the rows accordingly, and continues down reading the data would be optimal.

To specify:

Column 1 -- -- -   Column 2 -- - Column 3

12:00:01 - - - - - - - 67 - - - -- - - --  - - 0

12:00:02 - - - - - - - 72 - - - - - - - - - - 0

12:00:03 - - - - - - - 71 - - - - - - - - - - 0

12:00:04- - - -  - -- - 72 - - - - - - - - - - 0

12:00:05- - -  -- - - - 72 - - - --  - - - -  - 23

12:00:06- - - -  - -- - 73 - - - - - - - - - - 0

12:00:07 - -  - - - - -74 - -- - --- - - - - - 0

...............................

12:01:08 - - - - - - - - 67 - - - - - - - - - - 0

At 12:00:05, column 3 value is > 0 indicating criteria is met.
I need to then plot the 5 rows of data before and after that value, and then continue to search for more values > 0 in column 3 to ensure all values are plotted.

Also, in column 3, instead of plotting the value, would it be possible to indicate the criteria is met with a vertical line intersecting plot line of column 2? Not sure if this is in matplotlib library.

I am familiar with python, but have never attempted something like this. Is probably a layup for an experienced coder, but I am stuck in my tracks. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r' - - - - ')

print(data)
```

Comment: Hi Kenneth, welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes, I don't have much as of yet but simply have:import pandas, pandas read csv, and print dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You could try a version of the following:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
for i in range(len(df)+1):
  if df['Column3'][i] > 0:
    col1.extend(df['Column1'][i-5:i])
    col1.extend(df['Column1'][i:i+6])
    col2.extend(df['Column2'][i-5:i])
    col2.extend(df['Column2'][i:i+6])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(col1, col2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Returned "KeyError: 105"

Comment: changed for i in range(len(df) + 1):  -  to for i in range(len(df)):